# Expert or Master loot in a Journey world?

Tags: terraria

If I defeat a boss in a Journey world while the difficulty is set to Master, will that boss drop their Master-exclusive item(s)? What about Expert loot?

Answer (score 5):

A boss defeated while the difficulty is set to Master will drop the same items it would on a Master world - meaning its Master level items, its Expert level items, and its regular drops.

Similarly, a boss defeated while the difficulty is set to Expert level will drop its Expert level items and its regular drops.